# Unable to add pattern to anyURI field in xsd

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to add a pattern to anyURI such a way that I could eliminate leading/trailing and spaces in between, because copy paste errors are creating a lot of issues.

So far I was able to come up with this

```
<element name="randomUri">
   <simpleType>
     <restriction base="anyURI"><pattern value="\S(.*\S)?"/></restriction>
   </simpleType>
</element>
```

but when I try to validate it against an xml it looks like like it's not matching the pattern and I could give leading/trailing and spaces in between. This pattern worked perfectly if I used it against a string i.e when I made `base="string"` in my restriction. Is there some unique property of anyURI that doesn't allow me to do this?

P.S :I did not go the `pattern value = "http://.*` way because I wanted to accommodate for custom schemes like `sample.app://sampleapp.`for e.g

Just to make things clear...I want to eliminate leading/trailing and spaces in between for a url. The pattern I used above works totally fine if it `randomUri` was a `string` but it isn't working when I make `randomUri` an `anyURI`.

Comment: How does your XML look like? This would be interesting, because it would create a [mcve].

Comment: Something in the lines of `<randomURI>http://support.example.com</randomURI>` or `<randomURI>sample.app://sampleapp</randomURI>` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xs:anyURI` type has a `whiteSpace` facet of `collapse`, which means that leading and trailing spaces are stripped from the value before testing it against the `pattern` facet. This basically means that leading and trailing spaces are always allowed (and considered ignorable) and cannot be prevented using the `pattern` facet.

Comment: That really opened my mind. I finally used this pattern `<restriction base="anyURI"><pattern value="\S+"/></restriction>` so as to not allow spaces in between URI's and just trusting `anyURI` for taking care of leading and trailing spaces. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with the (small) sample you provided and one of the problems with it seems to be that you didn't specify the quantity on the `xs:element`. So it didn't fail on the `xs:pattern`, it **did fail on the first `xs:pattern`**. So you should have specified a quantifier on the `xs:element`:

```
<element name="randomUri" maxOccurs="unbounded">
...
```

Another simple suggestion may be to specify zero or more SPACE characters before and after the URI by using `\S*` instead of `\S`. Maybe that will improve the matching.

Comment: Isn't it that unspecified quantity defaults both minOccurs and maxOccurs to 1. Do I explicitly need to specify it?

Comment: The default values for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` are 1. So if you don't specify `maxOccurs` you can only have one `randomUri` element in your XML per definition in your XSD. I was surprised, too.

Comment: Just to make things clear...I want to eliminate leading/trailing and spaces in between for a url. The pattern I used above works totally fine if it `randomUri` was a `string` but it isn't working when I make `randomUri` an `anyURI`.

Comment: This is the problem when there is no [mcve]. We do not have the same _"playing ground"_. I wrote my answer in the assumption that we had one. On my computer, the sample does work as expected after adding the `maxOccurs="unbounded"`. But what may be wrong on your side - I cannot even guess...

Comment: Makes sense, I will try debugging on my side if there are some configurations that are hindering my goal. Thanks for your response.